# Intuition behind equation of line using normal vector and point

Tags: geometry

We have a normal vector $\vec{n}=(n_x,n_y)$ and point on the line $P=(p_x,p_y)$

Equation of the line is: $$n_x \cdot x + n_y \cdot y = n_xp_x + n_yp_y$$

What is the intuition behind this equation? I couldn't find any source that explain logical conclusion of this definition of straight line using normal vector and point.

Comment: Write it this way: $$n_x(x-p_x)+n_y(y-p_y)=0$$ and think "dot product".

Comment: Yeah so intuition is, we have point $M = (x, y)$ which lies on the line perpendicular to the vector $\vec{|MP|}$ and dot product of $\vec{n}$ (which is part of this line) with vector $\vec{|MP|}$ is 0. Which is this equation precisely.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Observe that:

\begin{align*}
n_x \cdot x + n_y \cdot y &= n_xp_x + n_yp_y\\
n_x \cdot (x-p_x) + n_y \cdot (y-p_y) &=0.
\end{align*}

Thus, the points that satifies the equation are those such that the vector $(x-p_x,y-p_y)$ is perpendicular to the normal vetor $(n_x,n_y)$.

Answer (score 0):

Consider the distance between origin and the line, say $\vec{X}$ is $C$. The dot product of vector $\vec{n}$ with any point on $\vec{X}$ will be equal to $C$ since it is the projection of that vector on a normal line passing through origin. So:

$\vec{n}.\vec{X} = \vec{n}.\vec{P} = C$

Which gives the equation $n_x.x + n_y.y = n_x.p_x + n_y.p_y$